# Displaying JSON as list in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I want to display the list of the data (received as JSON) but it looks like I am missing something and it does not display the data. Here's my code:

Service:

```
 getData() {
    this.http.post('http://localhost/api/Acc/GetData', "").subscribe(res => {
    return res;
   });
 }
```

Component:

```
  constructor(private api: ApiService) {
     var data = api.getData();   
  }
```

Template:

```html
<mat-list>
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of data">
<h4 matLine> {{item.Field1}} </h4>
</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

There are some weak points I can see:

1. I am not sure if `getData` uses the proper way of returning the data
2. I am not sure whether constructor properly stores the data, but I tried some other options and nothing helped.

Comment: Welcome.  Please read how to create an [mcve] - for questions like this, it's required in order to understand the actual issue you are having.  Also, you can use your browser's developer tools to find out _exactly_ what the API call is returning....

Comment: That's definitely wrong. `return res` is **inside the callback**, your `getData` method overall returns `undefined`. I'd recommend running through https://angular.io/tutorial, which includes how to handle async data. Also I'd suggest putting some types in your method and property definitions, so `tsc` can tell you more about what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's Tour of Heroes tutorial offers one way to retrieve a list of objects from a server in section 6, HTTP - Get Heroes with HTTPClient:

```
/** GET heroes from the server */
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
}
```

The rest of the tutorial (https://angular.io/tutorial) provides context for how to import the necessary modules to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getData()` method should return an Observable, because fetching data is asynchronous.

In your component you can subscribe to that Observable and display the data if you receive them.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-data',
  templateUrl: './some-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some-data.component.css']
})
export class SomeDataComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any[];

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getData().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of data">{{item | json}}</div>
</div>
```

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiService {

  // constructor, etc.

  getData(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.post<any[]>('http://localhost/api/Acc/GetData', "");
  }
}
```

You also can subscribe to the observable in the html, via the `async` pipe.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-data',
  templateUrl: './some-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some-data.component.css']
})
export class SomeDataComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.api.getData();
  }
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="(data | async) as items">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">{{item | json}}</div>
</div>
```